# Getting max and min from two different sets in json

Tags: d3.js

I haven't found a solution with data set up quite like mine...

```
var marketshare = [
    {"store": "store1", "share": "5.3%", "q1count": 2, "q2count": 4, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store2","share": "1.9%", "q1count": 5, "q2count": 10, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store3", "share": "2.5%", "q1count": 3, "q2count": 6, "q3count": 0}
];
```

Code so far, returning undefined...

```
var minDataPoint = d3.min( d3.values(marketshare.q1count) ); //Expecting 2 from store 1 
var maxDataPoint = d3.max( d3.values(marketshare.q2count) ); //Expecting 10 from store 2
```

I'm a little overwhelmed by `d3.keys`, `d3.values`, `d3.maps`, converting to array, etc. Any explanations or nudges would be appreciated.

Comment: @mdml, this should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this instead:

```
d3.min(marketshare, function(d){ return d.q1count; }) // => 2.
```

You can pass an accessor function as the second argument to [`d3.min`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_min)/[`d3.max`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_max).